# Pubnub Client Server Chat (iOS)

Tags: ios, parse-platform, chat, messaging, pubnub

I'm trying to make a simple chat application for iOS using pubnub (and parse) and having trouble knowing what I should be doing. I was wondering if it is possible to do this using the pubnub framework;

So I have two clients; A and B, and the Pubnub server.
If I want to send a message to client B, it goes something like this

```
sender:myID receiver:destinationID message:hello.
```

Then the server parses this data and sees the receiver and sends it to the receiver's channel. Can I do this? If so how?. If I can't, what instead should I be doing. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, have a look at this, the example works well. It just sends a message from A to B

http://www.pubnub.com/docs/objective-c/iOS/ios-sdk.html

Answer (score 0):

@rici the example @neva posted is pretty much the way to go for basic publishing. If you need richer examples, or guidance, feel free to also contact us at support@pubnub.com and we're happy to assist further.